# adding division to a current HTML using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following javascript function :

```
function addNewUpload()
{

if(formNumber == 1){
displayRemove();
}

if(formNumber != 10){
document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += " <div id='u_"+(formNumber+1)+"' > ";
document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += " description : <input type='text' name='desc[]' /> <br> ";
document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += " photo : <input type='file' name='file[]' />   ";
document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += " </div> ";
formNumber = formNumber + 1;
}else{
alert("You can only upload 10 photos.");
}
}
```

the code above works fine except that the holder division with the `id='u_"+(formNumber+1)+"'` doesnt wrap the content in it self so I get this result :

```
<div id="u_2"> </div> 
description : <input type="text" name="desc[]"> <br>
  photo : <input type="file" name="file[]">      
<div id="u_3"> </div> 
description : <input type="text" name="desc[]"> <br>  
photo : <input type="file" name="file[]">     
 <div id="u_4"> </div> description : <input type="text" name="desc[]"> <br>  photo : <input type="file" name="file[]">     </div>
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use the code below. Each time you call `.innerHTML = ..`, the string is parsed in an attempt to make it valid HTML. So, unclosed tags are closed, and single closing tags are ignored.

```
var html = " <div id='u_"+(formNumber+1)+"' > ";
html += " description : <input type='text' name='desc[]' /> <br> ";
html += " photo : <input type='file' name='file[]' />   ";
html += " </div> ";
document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += html;
```

Your code is interpreted as:

```
+= " <div id='u_"+(formNumber+1)+"' > </div>";                 // Added </div>
+= " description : <input type='text' name='desc[]' /> <br> "; // Same
+= " photo : <input type='file' name='file[]' />   ";          // Same
+= " </div> ";                                                 // Ignored
```

Comment: great :) it works perfectly fine but why wasnt the my code working?

Comment: @AhouraGhotbi That's explained at the bottom of my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Don't repeatedly use `innerHTML`. Build up a single string, *then* add it to the `innerHTML`.

```
function addNewUpload()
{
    if(formNumber == 1) displayRemove();

    if(formNumber != 10)
    {
        formNumber++;
        var html = " <div id='u_" + formNumber + "' > "
            + " description : <input type='text' name='desc[]' /> <br> "
            + " photo : <input type='file' name='file[]' />   "
            + " </div> ";

        document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += html;
    }
    else
    {
        alert("You can only upload 10 photos.");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The browser will automatically "fix" the bare `<div>` tag by closing it after appending the first time. A `div` element has to be closed with `</div>` and this will be done automatically if you don't provide `</div>`

You can avoid this by passing everything in one go, so that no fixes are made in between:

```
document.getElementById('uploadHolder').innerHTML += " <div id='u_"+(formNumber+1)+"' > "
+ " description : <input type='text' name='desc[]' /> <br> "
+ " photo : <input type='file' name='file[]' />   "
+ " </div> ";
```